# solving a sequence problem

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-theorem

$ a_n = (1+ \frac{1} {n}) ^n  $ where n is a natural number then which one is greater $ a_{2013} $ or $ a_{2014} ?$

I tried using binomial expansion but could not solve it. I also tried using monotonicity but expression is complicated.